# Nemo: open URI in existing window

Tags: linux-mint, file-management, nemo

The question is about [Nemo file manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemo_(file_manager)), which is default for Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon.

Is it possible to achieve behavior similar to google chrome or other browsers? When I have an instanve of chrome already running and I execute command `google-chrome www.some-url.com` the new window won't be created, but instead the URL will open in existing chrome window as a new tab.

Nemo file browser opens a new window every time I click on the link to the local file, folder or execute a command `nemo \some\local\path`

What I would ideally like is for Nemo to mantain single instance (window) unless it has been explicitely told to open a new window, just as most web browsers do. I really don't mind if Nemo opens a new tab or uses the existing one to open the url that has been passed to it as long as new window is not created.

Has anyone tried to achieve such behavior? Is it possible at all? Any suggestions?

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/issues/461

Comment: 5 years later, the github thread is locked and feature is not in development. Maybe not so many people actually need it...

Comment: @ArtGertner Oh a lot of people wanted it and reacted with +1. The devs just locked it for no reason.

Comment: I know it is an ugly hack, but I achieved something like this by using PyAutoGUI of Python.

Comment: @ankit, can you please share the solution? Maybe post it as an answer. Thanks

Comment: If relevant, Dolphin opens new tabs in the running instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
nemo --tabs "/home/name/folder1" --tabs "/home/name/folder2" --tabs "/home/name/folder3"
```